# Does iOS Mail App Compose Screen Use UITableView? If so, why?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Is the iOS 7 Apple Mail app is using a UITableview for the composing and viewing message screens? If so, why?

[image]
The composition screen appears to be using a UITableView with a UITextfield for the subject row and a UITextView for the message row. What is the benefit? There aren't any table rows similar enough to be reused (Max is 6 if you include cc and bcc), so I don't see a performance benefit. There is no Edit mode (i.e. move, delete rows) on these two screens. The resizing table rows necessary to accommodate long messages seems like an unnecessary headache.

I'm working on an app with a similar text input layout and number of fields. I initially planned to use a UIViewController with UITextField and UITextView placed on a UIScrollView. Examining the Mail app, I'm assuming there's a reason Apple would use a UITableView. Though I don't see what it is.

Insight appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, What UITableView does better than UIScrollView is how it handles placing the different elements one below the other. Using just a UIScrollView, you would have to manage said placement by yourself which can become headachy when you have to handle conditionnally hidden rows (like CC/BCC).

Answer (score 1):

Table views are REALLY good at a few things, and one of those things is creating forms. All you really need to do is add the fields to the cells and do a little cell customization, and the table view handles all the spacing, formatting, rotation, scrolling, etc.

I built an open source iOS form building library that is build on top of UITableView for just these reasons. (https://github.com/mamaral/MAFormViewController) In my case, if you need to move around or add a new field to the form, it's as simple as updating the data source with a new form-field cell, as opposed to creating a totally new textField, configuring it, determining the frame, moving everything above and below it around accordingly, etc. I would *suspect* these reasons are similar to why Apple would use table views for forms like the above.

Answer (score 0):

The class chain is:

NSObject - everything subclasses this. you have to be really crazy to not subclass it

UIResponder - anything that responds to user input should be a subclass of this. the message view responds to user input

UIView - anything that draws to the screen should subclass this. the message view draws to the screen

UIScrollView - anything that scrolls should subclass this (note: that's not how it works on OS X! Only on iOS!). The message view scrolls, so it needs to subclass UIScrollView

UITableView - anything that has rows of data should subclass this. The message view has four rows, so it should subclass it.

Basically, it subclasses UITableView because it needs all of UITableView's functionality. So why not subclass it? You are saving yourself thousands of lines of code by doing so.

Duplicating all of UITableView's functionality is very difficult.

Chances are if you write an app without subclassing UITableView, it will be so sucky Apple might even reject it from the store, telling you to go back and make it work properly. Which would mean subclassing UITableView or else writing thousands of lines of code — for example Voice Over is a huge pain in the ass if you don't subclass UITableView.

If you don't want to restrict yourself to rows of data, consider using a Collection View.

Comment: Thanks for the class chain education. My point was, the simple mail composition screen does NOT need all of UITableView functionality.  It's 4 rows. No reuse of rows occurs (i.e. performance benefit). No Edit mode (i.e. More, Delete, Reorder functions). So why use the table? I wouldn't need thousands of lines of code. Why not just drop a few UITextFields and a UITextView on a view? I assume they have a reason, but it's not apparent to me in this instance.